# Adding Top/Bottom border to TextView programmatically

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView and I need to put a black border on the top of it.
The view is created in java, so I can't use the classic XML divider trick.
Many answers here suggest to put a black line as a background. I tried, but I found out that zooming in the view results in the line overflowing its content (in my application the views' textSizes are constantly changed by pinch zooming, so I can't know a definite width in advance.
So, my question is: is there a simple way to add a top border to a TextView which adapts to its size and which can be created from java without using XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Compound Drawables](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawables%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29). They can be set by XML or in Code.

Use [nine patch images](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) for the Drawables or even [Shape drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) and they should scale ok with the TextView.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's basically what I was looking for!

Comment: You should rephrase your question like requested above to prevent it from being removed.